# Using route variables in route definition

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to dynamically invoke a bespoke controller based on a variable provided by the request.

```
Route::get('/{variable}', function($variable){
// Invoke controller, something like this...:
//{$variable}Controller@index
})
```

How?

Comment: why not have one controller invoke various action classes based on the variable?

Comment: What is an "action class"?

Comment: action classes are a design pattern https://rezakhademi.medium.com/what-are-laravel-action-classes-and-how-to-use-them-253217c43b06

Comment: Latest comment had the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Controller are not really meant to be used like that. Why not create any other class to handle your logic?

When you have logic that might be duplicated between controllers, the solution is never to use one controller inside another, the solution is to extract that logic to a new class that can be used in both places.

Example create a register action class (any php class works)

```php
namespace App\Actions;

class RegisterAction
{
  public static function handle()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now based on your `$variable`, link your variable to your implementation. You can use a match, switch statement, factory class or any other method.

```php
Route::get('/{variable}', function($variable){
  $action = match($variable) {
    "register" => App\Actions\RegisterAction::class,
    ...
  };
  
  return $action::handle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Not a perfect solution but it works

```
Route::get('/{variable}', function($variable){
    $className = "App\Http\Controllers\\". $variable ."Controller";
    echo $className::index();
});
```

In this example all Controllers need to have same namespace